# can't export project to eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, data-migration

I'm trying to export a project to eclipse IDE and im doing all the first steps correctly. I managed to fill in the security information eg. security token and everything then I select that I want to migrate all the pages components and static resources. and when i click finish it updates for a while and the freezes. It says Request status : In Progress and then after a couple of minutes it says "

```
Unable to create project 
Reason : OutOfmemory Javaheap space"
```

I don't know why it says that. It's a new laptop running on Linux so there is plenty of memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a problem of eclipse, not of system. Please add some more JVM memory in eclipse.ini file (in Eclipse folder)

-vmargs

-Xms128m

-Xmx512m

-XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Hey. I went to the Ini file and there were following lines there :-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest

Comment: is there a way to increase the size ?

Comment: You might want to edit -Xmx2048m and -Xms1024m. It will increase the heap size of JVM in eclipse.